Rotation along line in $\mathbb R^3$
Let $\rho: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ denote the linear transformation that is a $\pi/4$ anticlockwise rotation around the line generated by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. i.e., $\rho\left(\;\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\;\right)=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 2 / 2 \\ -\sqrt 2/2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. Explain how to find $\rho\left(\;\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\;\right)$, and then write the matrix representation of $\rho$ in the standard basis $[\rho]_{e,e}$.

I am still quite new to change of basis and matrix representations in general, so I am not 100% sure where to go with this question. Currently, I'm thinking of maybe using a change of basis to make the line/axis of rotation collinear with one of the new axes, then simply apply the $\mathbb R^3$ rotation matrix, i.e., this one around the $x$-axis:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0\\ 
0&\cos\frac \pi 4 & -\sin \frac \pi 4 \\ 
0& \sin \frac \pi 4 & \cos \frac \pi 4 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$ in "that world/coordinate system". To find such a basis, I thought about taking $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ to be one of the basis vectors, then simply finding two perpendicular vectors. However, I am currently stuck on how exactly to flesh out the details of how to execute this plan (mainly the coordinate representation and change of basis parts). Any input would be much appreciated.

Can Rodrigues' rotation formula help you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

I don't think I am supposed to use that as I think it is testing my understanding of change of basis

Given a unit vector $u$ specifying an axis of rotation, first find an orthonormal basis $v,w$ for the normal plane to $u$ as you say.
Then the matrix $C = \begin{bmatrix}u&v&w\end{bmatrix}$ moves the standard basis to the $u,v,w$-basis, while $C^{-1}$ moves the $u,v,w$-basis to the standard one.
Therefore the matrix $CRC^{-1}$, where $R$ is some rotation about the $x$-axis, first moves your rotational basis to the standard one, then performs the rotation in standard coordinates, and finally transforms back.
Note it is also important to put $v,w$ in the correct order so that the $C$ is orientation preserving (has positive determinant), else the sign of the angle will be reversed.

Note that for orthonormal matrix $C$, it holds that $C^{-1}=C^T$. This may speed up the computation.
